# Close app when hitting back button on android

Tags: android, button, exit, back

So my login Activity is the first screen you see. When you hit the back button, it exits the app, good. So I open up the app again. After logging in, I am now in my main Activity. How do I make it so when I hit the back button now, it exits the app rather than going back to the login Activity?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you push the new activity, call finish() on the previous, otherwise it will remain on the stack, therefore appearing when you hit back and pop the current activity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: that did it, thanks! I'll have to accept your answer in 11 minutes apparently.

Comment: why do I have to wait so long to accept an answer on here? I am fairly new to this voting/accepting answer thing

Comment: I think it's just to allow for people to get their answers in if someone else was typing theirs up. That way the person who posted the question can choose who gets the Accepted check.

Comment: gotcha...thanks. I thought it was because I was new to these forums

Answer (score 0):

try this one
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {

super.onBackPressed(); 
finish();

}