# how to close app when i press back?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button

I'm installing my app then save data using Main Activity and going to another  Fragment activity.Next time I'm starting my App always  preview second Fragment then I press back going to Main Activity But I don't want to go Main Activity.I want press back button close My App.I try this

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                // handle back button's click listener
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Back press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: did you call finish() when you make your intents?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application  go through this link

Comment: @KristiyanVarbanov Can't call finish() in fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close app when hitting back button on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902464/close-app-when-hitting-back-button-on-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your Mainactivity,  after the line `startActivity()` for starting second activity add this line `this.finish();`

Answer (score 1):

try some like this in your onBackPress method

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        //to clear all old opened activities 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

--Simplest way to close/exit app :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this thread can help you: [Android: Quit application when press back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591959/android-quit-application-when-press-back-button)

Let's say your Main Activity is B and the Fragment activity is A. Then, you must clear the stack of activities and leave only A on the stack. Use this:

```
Intent launchNextActivity;
launchNextActivity = new Intent(B.class, A.class);
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                  
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(launchNextActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPressed method in your main activity

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
       }